# How to Refresh or Use Firebase Access Token for Microsoft Graph API in Angular App?

Tags: node.js, angular, firebase, microsoft-graph-api

I'm developing an Angular application that uses Firebase (Firestore, Hosting and Authentication) as its backend. I'm integrating the Microsoft Graph API into my application and facing an issue with authorization tokens.

When a user logs in via Firebase using the Microsoft provider, I receive credentials that include an "action_token". This token, as I understand, is valid for one hour. But works well with a graph api call.
Additionally, when I perform getAuth(), I receive a refresh_token and an access_token through the stsManager. However, when I try to use this access_token to access the Microsoft Graph API, I encounter the error: "required claim nbf not present in token".

I'm looking for advice on three fronts:

- How can I refresh the access_token aquired by login in via firebase into microsoft with  for continuous use with the Microsoft Graph API?
- Is there a way to use the access_token obtained through stsManager in conjunction with the Microsoft Graph API?
- Is ther a much beter way to do this al together?

Any insights or guidance on how to resolve these issues would be greatly appreciated.

what I've tried so far:
I've been working on integrating the Microsoft Graph API into my Angular application that utilizes Firebase for backend services (Firestore, Hosting, and Authentication). When I login using the Microsoft provider in Firebase, I retrieve credentials that include an 'action_token.' My understanding is that this token is valid for an hour. This token does authenticate my requests to the Microsoft Graph API.

I used the getAuth() method, which provided me with a refresh_token and an access_token via the stsManager. I anticipated that the access_token would allow me to make authenticated requests to the Microsoft Graph API but I encountered an error stating 'required claim nbf not present in token.

Comment: The tokens you get from `getAuth` are specific to Firebase. It's unlikely you can use those on Microsoft's APIs. You might be able to get the OAuth token from Microsoft's provider though, so I hope somebody has an example of that.

Comment: Are you login in users from Microsoft Entra(Azure AD) or Microsoft accounts on the app? If yes, have you checked MSAL for Angular https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/lib/msal-angular

Comment: No, I'm login them in via the Firebase authentication.

Comment: Then how are you using Microsoft Graph API when users are being authenticated by Firebase?

Answer (score 0):

To be able to call Microsoft Graph API, you must have a token issued by Microsoft Entra (formerly Azure AD).

To get that, you will either be authenticating users with identities in Entra See [MSAL for Angular](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/lib/msal-angular) or using a client credentials that are issued by Entra.

In your case you seem to be mixing up tokens. Tokens issued by Firebase are only for calling firebase/google APIsthat the IDP protects. You may need to explain how Microsoft Graph API and firebase are related in your context to be able to get a solution.